# How would I add mysql_real_escape_string() to this QUERY?

Tags: php, mysql, get

I'm using a `.Jquery autocomplete` function and I'm tring to figure out where can put the `mysql_real_escape_string()` at. I've tried a few different ideas but I'm just not sure. I get an error of...

```
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost'
```

When I use `$ac_term = mysql_real_escape_string("%".$_GET['term']."%");` I'm not even sure if that the right way to use it.

Here's what I have...

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
} 


try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

$return_arr = array();

if ($conn)
{
    $ac_term = "%".$_GET['term']."%"; 

    $query = "SELECT 

    CONCAT_WS('', '(',User_ID,') ', UserName, ' (',AccessLevel,')') AS DispName,
    User_ID, UserName, AccessLevel

    FROM Employees
    WHERE UserName LIKE :term
    OR User_ID LIKE :term
    OR AccessLevel LIKE :term

";

    $result = $conn->prepare($query);
    $result->bindValue(":term",$ac_term);
    $result->execute(); 

while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        $row_array['value'] = $row['DispName'];
        $row_array['User_ID'] = $row['User_ID'];    
        $row_array['UserName'] = $row['UserName'];
        $row_array['AccessLevel'] = $row['AccessLevel'];

        array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
    }

}
$conn = NULL;
echo json_encode($return_arr);
?>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: possibly this should help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191801/using-mysql-real-escape-string-with-pdo-no-connection-to-localhost-server

Comment: Hint: you could use PDO::FetchAll instead or while loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to add mysql_real_escape_string() to this query at all.
Just leave your code as is.

Comment: his question was how to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` not how to implement parameterized queries.

Comment: "How would I add mysql_real_escape_string() **to this QUERY?**" it actually was. Go figure.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `mysql_real_escape_string` is not a right method to be used with PDO, for escaping purpose use PDO [`quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php) method.

As stated in documentation, escaping string is not necessary for `prepare` and `execute` statements:

> Calling PDO::prepare() and PDOStatement::execute() for statements that will be issued multiple times with different parameter values optimizes the performance of your application by allowing the driver to negotiate client and/or server side caching of the query plan and meta information, and helps to prevent SQL injection attacks by eliminating the need to manually quote the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Prepared statement parameters don't need to be escaped; it's one of the main reasons for them.

Some PDO drivers don't currently support [repeating a named parameter](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48856). Depending on which version of PHP is installed, you may need to create a separate parameter for each value.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create the connection first.  `mysql_real_escape_string()` relies on an active MySQL connection; it's trying to assume your credentials will let you connect to localhost most likely.

create an active, authenticated mysql connection prior to using `mysql_real_escape_string()`, and at least that error message should go away.

Additionally, the best way to use it would be:

```
$ac_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['term']);
```

with your query looking like

```
$query = "SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE column LIKE '%$ac_term%'";
```

Comment: ...and if you downvote, perhaps an explanation?  I'd think you'd know better.

Comment: "How would I add `mysql_real_escape_string()`"... then he cited the error he was receiving.  There are other problems with this but the **question** asked was fairly clear.

Comment: Op is using [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) with a [prepared statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) therefor you won´t need mysql_real_escape_string.

Comment: Consider how the question is used.  Someone will google something similar to the OP's question, looking for an answer along a similar vein.  Ignoring the question and posting just what you think is wanted is a disservice to the SO community.  I do not argue that OP should either use PDO or not PDO, but my answer is the only one that addressed his **question**, regardless of the context.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: sometimes the question is the wrong one; the disservice is in letting a developer take the wrong path. That's why the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) is a problem.

Comment: -1: `mysql_real_escape_string` [should not be used](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6191801/90527) with any DB extension other than the old mysql extension (which shouldn't be used at all in new code).